# How can I use a prediction model (e.g., ARMA model or LSTM) for multi-variate data?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, predictive-models, dataset

I have a question

I have had a dataset below

```
             sensor1   sensor2  sensor3 ...
2021-01-01    1.32       2.2      1.0
2021-01-02    4.3        2.0      0.8 ...
...
```

I know ARMA model is useful for time-series forecasting

[image]

However, how can I use ARMA model for data with multiple attributes ?

If data with a single attribute can be a input for ARMA model, should I aggregate the attribute set?
(for example, after normalizing each attribute, I add up all values every rows to transform all attributes to a single attribute)

Comment: Are you forecasting your three sensors? Or are the sensors potential predictors for something else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are forecasting each timeseries, but it could be useful for you take a look at VARIMA where each timestep could consist of a vector of attributes. On the other side, you could use ARIMAX which is ARIMA, but with exogenous variables, which are in your case your other attributes.

There are many ways to tackle this problem. These two are some of the simpler ones, but who knows, they might do the trick.